# How to add a Null Value record in a temporary table?

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have one table 'AgentEventStats' that has Agent IDs and their names. I use this table in a dataset that pulls up agent names to use a parameter for a Stats report. (This is to *exclude* those agents for my report).

However, I *have* to select an agent for that parameter or else my report won't work. That means that if I don't want to exclude any agents, (NULL value) I cannot run that report.

So, I thought, I would insert a Null value in a temp table that includes the AgentEventStats records.

What I tried:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT AgentReporting, AgentFirstName + ' ' + AgentLastName [AgentName]
    INTO #AgentStats    -- First, creating the temp table.
    FROM AgentEventStats
    WHERE MidnightStartDate >= dateadd(day, -60, getdate())--'2017-01-01'
    AND MidnightStartDate <  getdate() --dateadd(day,1,'2017-03-13')
    ORDER BY AgentName

    INSERT INTO #AgentStats (AgentReporting, AgentName)  --Then, inserting the Null value in that temp table.
    VALUES ('100', 'No Agents');
```

This doesn't work. I get an error message:

> There is already an object named '#AgentStats' in the database.

Someone suggested I use a Union All instead. Can someone guide me please?

Comment: Do you get this same error if you run the code using Management Studio, using a different (new) connection?

Comment: I AM using SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Comment: I will ask again... did you try this same query in a different (new) connection?

Comment: No, I haven't tried a different connection. So, my code is right? It's just the tool I'm using that's wrong?

Comment: Your code is okay, you are missing one thing. I will post an answer in a minute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the code like it is more than once in the same connection, you will get that error.

Quick fix: add `DROP TABLE #AgentStats` to the end of the script.

Then run just that line once (to drop the temp table).

Then you can run the whole script over and over again without error. Add in a `SELECT * FROM #AgentStats` before the drop to see what is in the table before you get rid of it.

Another way to do this is to first check to see if the temp table exists, then drop it before running the rest of the script. Like so:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AgentStats') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #AgentStats

SELECT DISTINCT...
```

If you do it this way, you won't need the `DROP TABLE` at the end any more.

Hope this helps you out.

**EDIT**

The UNION solution.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AgentReporting, AgentFirstName + ' ' + AgentLastName [AgentName]
FROM AgentEventStats
WHERE MidnightStartDate >= dateadd(day, -60, getdate())--'2017-01-01'
AND MidnightStartDate <  getdate() --dateadd(day,1,'2017-03-13')
UNION ALL -- added ALL based on comment
SELECT '100', 'No Agents'
ORDER BY 2;
```

Comment: I had already tried that, Mr. Richards. It runs fine in SSMS. I get  'Commands completed succesfully'    >>>>>  But when I add that code to the dataset in my report builder, it doesn't update the fields. Also, under Parameters, I can select the dataset I just edited. But the Value field and Label field in that windows are empty. Can't select the field and label. Hence, the report doesn't work.  >>> Error message:> The report parameter 'AgentName uses the field 'AgentID' in a dataset reference but the dataset 'Agents' does not contain that field.

Comment: I have added a UNION based solution that may work for you.

Comment: YES YES YES!!!! This worked!!! Yaaayyy... Thank you so much Mr. Richards.

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Comment: That should be a UNION ALL.  Using UNION forces a sort of the data to remove duplicates.

In this specific situation, UNION would be acceptable if the first query did not have a DISTINCT, but using them both is a waste of resources.